# Server side JWT for my react-redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner with `react` and `redux`. I have searched a lot but all I get is `server-side rendering`, but I don't want that (correct me if I'm wrong). What I want is this:

My react-redux app calls an `API` to get some `JSON` response. The problem is that there is no user authentication **(and won't be)**. Therefore I want to have a `Token` for my `API` calls. I need my react-redux app to obtain a token on the `server-side` from my locally hosted PHP (Laravel) app through an API or HTTP request. Then set that token for my `client-side` of the react-redux app.

I simply don't know where to start and how to have this `server.js` in my react-redux app.

Comment: What is the token for if you don't have any user authentication? If there is no user authentication, how can you prevent anybody from making the HTTP request and getting this API token?

Comment: @AJFunk If the token is generated server side on my react app then I would accept only valid tokens on my API (no direct access), so nobody could access it without at least going through my react app and getting a token from that app either validly or by tricking the app. Then I can focus on securing my app not my API. The API is a PHP app, completely independent.

Comment: in my opinion you will need to use a bundler (webpack will be good) you will then setup your client to fetch the token, then create a redux store to store your token. i really dont know if redux's store creation can support CommonJS or direct from browser use.

Comment: What I used to do is, in any API call token is passed to server & if token is not valid or not present, server issues un-authorized response. Client app can then force to redirect to login page & get the token from auth process. Once we get the token, keep it in local storage.

Comment: @HosseinJabbari you're not really adding any layers of security with this. What prevents anybody from making a HTTP request to your endpoint to fetch a token? You would prevent this by restricting what domains are allowed access. By doing that, you have no need for token since only your domain can access it. Without any user authentication, there is really no need for a JWT. A JWT stores encrypted information, but you have no user information to store in it

Comment: @anoop There is not authentication in my app and my API requires a token and I don't want to give the token directly to my client from the clien-side, want to pass it from the server-side which obtains it through a local http request to a PHP application that is the API itself.

Comment: @AJFunk there is no public endpoint. It's a local server endpoint.

Comment: This is mad confusing. There are likely so many ways to go about doing this. But why not just make a request to your node app from your frontend, which then makes a request to your php, which would then return the info to your node app, which could then return it to the frontend?

Comment: @AJFunk the domain can be spoofed easily in a hosts file.

Comment: @HosseinJabbari then how does your react app communicate with your API? If a user is using your app, it is running in their browser on their local machine. A HTTP request has to be made to your server to fetch the token, which means any machine can make that request and presumably fetch that token.

Comment: @Pytth this is exactly what I want. don't know how to implement a server side functionality in my react-redux app.

Comment: @Pytth I also want the response from the node app to my react-redux be rendered server side so the token request isn't seen by the client.

Comment: Im not understanding why you need a token? If you have two servers running, why not just: 1) Have your client make a request to Node. 2) Have node make a request to PHP. 3) When the PHP get's the request, it can check that you included some arbitrary secret/value in the req body ( if it's there, you are good; if it's not, then the req is rejected). Get what Im saying? No one would have access to variable values on your server unless you have some other vulnerability.

Comment: @Pytth !! sometimes I'm so entangled that I lose common sense. True what you said is most logical. Any good tutorials on how to implement a node app inside my react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good starter tutorial explaining how to hookup use Node and React together.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app